# Adding interaction term makes non-significant main effects significant

Tags: statistical-significance, interaction, interpretation, panel-data

I am running a fixed effect panel regression model.

Many people have asked/answered questions about significant main effects becoming non-significant after introducing interaction term. Well, my situation is quite different.

The model is rather straightforward, with $X_1$, $X_2$ as predictors. When I only included the main effects from $X_1$ and $X_2$ (both continuous), they were not remotely significant.

However, when their interaction term was included, not only did I get a significant interaction (negative coefficient), but the two main effects also became super significant with their coefficients swelling 4X+. I have a hard time understanding it.

I understand the interpretation of main effects with the interaction term in place is largely pointless. But if the main effects were initially not significant to start with (before introducing interaction term), can I still justify why I want to probe into their interaction?

In my report, should I say something like "we found no evidence that $X1$ is having a significant effect on the outcome variable, but we found its effect on the outcome variable is moderated by $X2$"?

Background: In terms of theory-building, $X1$ is the key variable that I believe should have a main effect based on literature, and such an effect, I argue, should be moderated by $X2$.